Why the mappingDefinitionId 0 by default in atlasmap?
I am using atlasmap for data mapping. I went through the code and found out atlasmap saves the mapping file to server with mappingDefinitionId as 0 by default. Why is it hardcoded like that? What is the significance of mappingDefinitionId?
